# Расположение файла для приложения

Tags: ios, xcode

Необходимо читать текстовый файл по сети (локальной) и выводить текст на экран.

Где лучше расположить файл - расшарить по сети или расположить на сервере типа Apache? Как открыть файл из папки с проектом (как путь прописать) и где его там положить?

Пока что-то указываю пути — а прога файла не видит.

**Обновление**

```
NSString* filePath = @"/192.168.1.210/projects/test.txt";
NSString *myText = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
if(myText==nil)
    [self.textview setText:@"Hello world!!!!"];
else
    [self.textview setText:myText];
```

**Обновление 2**

```
NSString* filePath = @"smb://192.168.1.189/Users/dieego/Desktop/share/test.txt";
NSError *error;
NSString *ps = [NSString  stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: &error];
if(ps==nil)
    [self.textview setText:[error localizedDescription]];
else
    [self.textview setText:ps];
```

Этот код выводит в textView

> "The operation couldnt be completed (Cocoa error 260)"

Comment: а как передаете ссылку на файл?

Comment: попробуйте добавить протокол 'http://192.168.....' и интересно посмотреть может error что нибудь прояснит.

Comment: есть что то в error? и я имел ввиду 'http' не 'smb'

Comment: поменял на http - все также ."The operation couldnt be completed (Cocoa error 260)"это в error

Comment: `NSFileReadNoSuchFileError` - 260 это нет файла. попробую у себя воспроизвести

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать `NSUrl * filePathURL = [NSUrl urlWithString:filePath];`

Comment: Используйте обрамление одинарными кавычками ` для выделения части кода.